# How do I get back into Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, wubi, disk

I just deleted root.disk in Windows 7 because it seemed at the time like the only way I could rename the new partition I had created (with wubi resize disk) to replace it as "root.disk" because when I tried to rename it OLDroot.disk it gave me an error saying I couldn't do that.

How do I get back into Ubuntu?

This new root.disk I created using this Wubi resize disk following all the steps I was hoping to rename the old partition, "OLDroot.disk" but since I couldn't I deleted it and now I can't get back into Ubuntu even though I did in the end after running chkdsk manage to rename my new partition (which had all the files of the old and now deleted root.disk) "root.disk".

Comment: Brendon Horne, could you please edit your question to add a little more clarity to it ? In particular, could you make shorter sentences ? Please explain what the initial situation was, what you did, what your problem is and finally what you try to do.

Comment: Please list the files in the `\ubuntu\disks` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you couldn't rename the root.disk it probably means there was some corruption. Which seems to have been confirmed after you couldn't rename the new.disk either until running chkdsk. By deleting the root.disk initially you haven't done yourself any favours, but hopefully the resize successfully completed before the corruption occurred.

If you've renamed the new.disk to root.disk and it isn't working, you may have better luck trying to recover the old root.disk. Maybe run the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) first to see what shape the new disk is in. Or try to open it with [ext2read](http://ext2read.blogspot.ca/) from Windows.

You can see whether chkdsk recovered the root.disk (even though you deleted it, the file still exists and windows may still have recovered). So have a look for it as described [here](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html). In short, look for the hidden `\found.???` directories, and check for a file named `file0000.chk` that's about the same size as your old root.disk:

```
C:\>dir /a:h
C:\>cd \found.000
C:\found.000>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is B4B7-99A8

 Directory of C:\found.000

19/07/2011  02:02 PM    15,000,000,000 file0000.chk
               1 File(s) 15,000,000,000 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  222,258,069,504 bytes free

C:\found.000>move file0000.chk \ubuntu\disks\root.disk
        1 file(s) moved.
```

NOTE: you have to run those commands from CMD.EXE that you selected **"Run as administrator"**.